# How can I solve findpeaks error in Octave

Tags: matlab, octave

```
theta = -90:0.01:90;      
for i=1:length(theta)
    SS = zeros(Nr,1);
    SS = exp(-1j*2*pi*d*(0:Nr-1)'*sind(theta(i))/lambda);
    PP = SS'*(Vn*Vn')*SS;
    Pmusic(i) = 1/ PP;
end
Pmusic = real(10*log10(Pmusic)); %Spatial Spectrum function
[pks,locs] = findpeaks(Pmusic,theta,'SortStr','descend','Annotate','extents');
MUSIC_Estim = sort(locs(1:K))
```

I want to run MUSIC matlab code in Octave (because I don't have matlab)

in matlab free 30day edition, It does work well but not in Octave.

> > error: findpeaks: non-string for Parameter name or Switch

how can I solve this error? I downloaded signal library and changed but it didn't work.

In Octave, provided matlab example works well. why doesn't work above code?

```
t = 2*pi*linspace(0,1,1024)';
 y = sin(3.14*t) + 0.5*cos(6.09*t) + 0.1*sin(10.11*t+1/6) + 0.1*sin(15.3*t+1/3);

 data = abs(y + 0.1*randn(length(y),1)); # Positive values + noise
 [pks idx] = findpeaks(data,"MinPeakHeight",1);

 dt = t(2)-t(1);
 [pks2 idx2] = findpeaks(data,"MinPeakHeight",1,...
                              "MinPeakDistance",round(0.5/dt));

 subplot(1,2,1)
 plot(t,data,t(idx),data(idx),'or')
 subplot(1,2,2)
 plot(t,data,t(idx2),data(idx2),'or')
plot(t,data,t(idx2),data(idx2),'or')
```

please help. thanks.

I tried

> > pkg install "https://github.com/gnu-octave/pkg-control/releases/download/control-3.5.2/control-3.5.2.tar.gz"

> > pkg install "https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/octave/Octave%20Forge%20Packages/Individual%20Package%20Releases/signal-1.4.3.tar.gz"

> > pkg load control

> > pkg load signal

in Octave command window but it didn't work.

This MUSIC algorithm matlab code is not written by me, but it's just a short calculator code, and I'll upload the entire code rather than write the code of the smaller version to see the value of MUSIC_Estim accurately.

```
DOA = [35 30];      %Direction of arrival (Degree)
T   = 200;         %Snapshots (or Samples)
K   = length(DOA); %The number of signal source(or traget)
Nr  = 9;          %Number of receiver's antennas
lambda = 1;      %Wavelength
d   = lambda/2;    %Receiver's antennas spacing
SNR = 10;           %Signal to Noise Ratio (dB)
A = zeros(Nr,K);   %Steering Matrix


for k=1:K
    A(:,k) = exp(-1j*2*pi*d*sind(DOA(k))*(0:Nr-1)'/lambda);
%Assignment matrix
end
Vj = diag(sqrt((10.^(SNR/10))/2));
s = Vj* ( randn(K,T) + 1j*randn(K,T) );
noise = sqrt(1/2)*(randn(Nr,T)+1j*randn(Nr,T));

X = A*s;
X = X+noise;      %Insert Additive White Gaussain Noise (AWGN)

% MUSIC (MUltiple SIgnal Classification)
Rx = cov(X');                     %Data covarivance matrix
[eigenVec,eigenVal] = eig(Rx);    %Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of Rx
Vn = eigenVec(:,1:Nr-K);          %Estimate noise subspace (Note that eigenvalues sorted ascendig on columns of "eigenVal")
theta = -90:0.01:90;       %Grid points of Peak Search
for i=1:length(theta)
    SS = zeros(Nr,1);
    SS = exp(-1j*2*pi*d*(0:Nr-1)'*sind(theta(i))/lambda);
    PP = SS'*(Vn*Vn')*SS;
    Pmusic(i) = 1/ PP;
end
Pmusic = real(10*log10(Pmusic)); %Spatial Spectrum function
[pks locs] = findpeaks(Pmusic, "DoubleSided");
locs = theta(locs);
MUSIC_Estim = sort(locs)

figure;
plot(theta,Pmusic,'-b',locs(1:K),pks(1:K),'r*'); hold on
text(locs(1:K)+2*sign(locs(1:K)),pks(1:K),num2str(locs(1:K)'))

xlabel('Angle \theta (degree)'); ylabel('Spatial Power Spectrum P(\theta) (dB)')
title('DOA estimation based on MUSIC algorithm ')
xlim([min(theta) max(theta)])
grid on
```

///
locs = theta(locs);
and
MUSIC_Estim = sort(locs)

value is not peak. so I tried

```
Pmusic = real(10*log10(Pmusic)); %Spatial Spectrum function
[pks,locs] = findpeaks(Pmusic, "DoubleSided","MinPeakHeight", 5);
[sorted_pks, sorted_idx] = sort(pks(1:K));  % Sort peaks in descending order
MUSIC_Estim = theta(locs(sorted_idx(1:K)))      % Select top K peak locations from sorted peaks

figure;
plot(theta,Pmusic,'-b',MUSIC_Estim,pks(1:K),'r*'); hold on
text(MUSIC_Estim(1:K)+2*sign(sorted_idx(1:K)),pks(1:K),num2str(MUSIC_Estim(1:K)'))
```

like this but it has another problem of sorting peak values and can't get more than 2 DOA.

Comment: Reading the Octave `findpeaks()` documentation is a good start (in other words, RTFM): https://octave.sourceforge.io/signal/function/findpeaks.html . Hint: Octave and Matlab are not 100% compatible. Although they are if considering the syntax and intrinsic functions, it's not always the case for the functions from the packages.

Comment: the below code which works well is included in octave.sourceforge.io/signal/function/findpeaks.html here. I tried but I don't know why only above findpeaks have error. I'm sorry.

Comment: Did you read the documentation I've linked to? Do the arguments of `findpeaks()` of your first example match the arguments described in the documentation? I don't think so.

Comment: [pks,locs] = findpeaks(Pmusic,"DoubleSided"); Now I know "DoubleSided" doesn't make error. But still don't know about difference findpeaks() between matlab and octave. In octave findpeaks(), can it get only 1 argument? and with above code, locs value is weird. I can't understand why this happen.

Comment: I'm so confused that original findpeaks(Pmusic,theta) matlab code have 2 'data' type but can Octave findpeaks() have only 1 'data' type argument? then do I have to fix for run this code in Octave?

Comment: In your updated code, for the plot you must use `sorted_pks` instead of `pks`

Comment: The solting problem was solved with your advice. However, when increasing the number of DOA is increased, there is still a problem of recognizing not only the maximum value but also the minimum value as peak.

Comment: MATLAB Home version costs EUR119.- https://de.mathworks.com/pricing-licensing.html?prodcode=ML&intendeduse=home or £105.- https://uk.mathworks.com/pricing-licensing.html?prodcode=ML&intendeduse=home or  $149. Do you have $149 to spare on MATLAB Home/Student genuine version?

Answer (score 1):

Basically [Octave findpeaks](https://octave.sourceforge.io/signal/function/findpeaks.html) supports a single argument for the data: `[pks, loc] = findpeaks(data)` return the peak values in `pks`, and their indexes in `loc`.

[Matlab findpeaks](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html) has an optional extra input argument that contains the abscissas of the data samples `[pks, loc] = findpeaks(data,x)`. On output, `loc` contains the abscissas of the peaks instead of the indexes.

But it's not the only difference. The Octave version doesn't have the `"SortStr"` property. But you don't need it as you are sorting afterwards anyway. It doesn't have either the `"Annotate"` property, but you don't need it either (from Matlab doc: "This argument is ignored if you call findpeaks with output arguments.")

At the end, in your first exemple you have to replace the `findpeaks` call by these two lines:

```
[pks,locs] = findpeaks(Pmusic);
locs = theta(locs)   % replaces the indexes by the theta values
```

Note that you could have got all of this by just **reading the documentations**.

Comment: Really appreciate for your attention. but     locs = theta(locs) makes weird value for locs and MUSIC_Estim. sorry.

Comment: What do you mean by "weird values" ? Please be more specific. Also, if you posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would help.

Comment: Are you suggesting that it would be better for me to rephrase the question, including the code I am currently working on, and submit it again? is that MRE?, right?

Comment: The question is OK as it is. But it would be helpful to update the code (by editing the question) so that we could just copy/paste it to Octave and run it to see by our own what are the problems. If your complete code is too long, just make a smaller version that still reproduces the problem.